# To end the instance created from VBA code in Task manager

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have written a VBA(Access) code to export data from Access database to Excel Worksheet. At the end of the code I have closed all the objects, Recordsets, worksheets and respectively 'nothing' is set.After the first run, I check the task Manager, I see an instance of Excel still exist in it. After the export, If I close the Access Database the instance in the Task Manager is ended. Is this normal ? or Do I have to edit my code?

Disdavantage: I am not able to run the code for second time when the database is still open.
Below is my code

```js
Public Sub Expdata()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim xlWBk As Object, Apxl As Object
    Dim wsMetaData As Worksheet
    Dim wsPlanning As Worksheet
    Dim PathEx As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Tempsheetname As String
    Dim blnEXCEL As Boolean

    blnEXCEL = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Apxl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set Apxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    blnEXCEL = True
    End If
    Err.Clear

    On Error GoTo 0
    PathEx = Forms("Export").Text14 'path comes from the directory given in form
    'Set Apxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWBk = Apxl.Workbooks.Open(PathEx)

    Tempsheetname = "Metadatasheet"
    Worksheets.Add.Name = Tempsheetname

    Set wsMetaData = xlWBk.Worksheets("Metadatasheet")
    Set wsPlanning = xlWBk.Worksheets("PlanningData")

    Apxl.Visible = True  'uncomment for debug to see excel file

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("LatestSNR")

    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        wsMetaData.Cells(1, i).Value = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i
    rst.MoveFirst

    wsMetaData.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    'calls Exp_Refresh module
    Call Exp_Refresh.RfData(xlWBk)

    Set xlWBk = Apxl.Workbooks.Open(PathEx)
    xlWBk.Sheets("Metadatasheet").Select
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    xlWBk.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlWBk.Sheets("Metadatasheet").Delete
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    xlWBk.Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Close all the objects and recordsets
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing


    xlWBk.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set xlWBk = Nothing
    Set wsMetaData = Nothing
    Set wsPlanning = Nothing

    If blnEXCEL = True Then Apxl.Quit
    Set Apxl = Nothing

    MsgBox "Export Successful !!!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please show how you instantiate and dispose the objects?

Comment: Please refer my code

Comment: You have not closed the instance of Excel, so it explains why it is still lingering. Before `Apxl.Quit` use `Apxl.Close` then Quit the app.

Comment: Thanks you! . But,it gives an error that 'object dosen't support this property or method(438 error)

Comment: I am sorry, you need to close the Excel Workbook object, not Excel App. Try `xlWBk.Close`

Comment: ;) .Thanks again. Still the same problem is persisting. After I close the access the instance in task manager is ended.

Comment: I'm always wary of `On Error Resume Next`. In this case `blnEXCEL = True` will be run whether the preceding line is successful or not. You might need to log on/off just to clear out all orphan processes that might be confusing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research.. I found the error point

```js
Tempsheetname = "Metadatasheet"
Worksheets.Add.Name = Tempsheetname
```

At this point it had lost its reference from the object. So if "Access app has ANY reference to an Excel resource, Excel won't close".

All I had to do was;

```js
 Tempsheetname = "Metadatasheet"
    xlWBk.Worksheets.Add.Name = Tempsheetname
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Excel not closing? Then CreateObject on the workbook, not ExcelApp.

Also if excel is set to visible then the rules of COM says you do not close if the user can see it.